# How to load url, what come from popoverclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

This is probably is pretty easy, but I'm stuck with it today.
The idea is that in my browser, I've create uiwebview and I want to implimate address bar in popover with it own class.
I can get the url from UItextfield from popover class to webview class, but when I get it uiwebview get lazy and it doesn't load it.
When I check it, debuger says that webview is null.
This is ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AdressBar.h"
#import "mypopoverController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AddressbarDelegate>

{
    UIWebView* mWebView;

    mypopoverController *popoverController;



}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* webPage;
@end
```

This is ViewController.m:

```
    #import "mypopoverController.h"
    #import "MyOwnPopover.h"
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "AdressBar.h"
    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize webPage = mWebView;
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
addressBar = [[AdressBar alloc] init];
    addressBar.delegate = self;
        [edittext addTarget:self action:@selector(showPopoverAdressBar:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.lv"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [mWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
        [mWebView setDelegate:self];
        [mWebView loadRequest:request];
}


     -(void)loadReceivedAddress:(NSURLRequest *)url{
            NSLog(@"url= %@", url);//there url always is not null and mWebView should load it
            if(mWebView != nil){
                [mWebView loadRequest:url];
            }else{
                    NSLog(@"mWebView is null");//...but there it say's that it's null
                }}
-(void)showPopoverAdressBar:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    AdressBar *popoverControllesr = [[AdressBar alloc]init];
    popoverControllesr.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 600, 45);
    popoverControllesr.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    popoverController = [[mypopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverControllesr];

    popoverController.cornerRadius = 20;
    if(_titles!=NULL){

        popoverController.titleText = _titles;}else{
            popoverController.titleText = @"Loading...";
        }
    popoverControllesr.address.text = absoluteString;



    popoverController.popoverBaseColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    popoverController.popoverGradient= YES;

    popoverController.arrowPosition = TSPopoverArrowPositionHorizontal;
    [popoverController showPopoverWithTouch:event];

}
@end
```

This is AdressBar.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol AddressbarDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)loadSomethingFromAddressBar:(NSURLRequest*)request;
@end
@interface AdressBar : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIButton *cancel;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLRequest *request;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <AddressbarDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

This is AdressBar.m:

```
#import "AdressBar.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AdressBar ()

@end

@implementation AdressBar
@synthesize delegate = delegate;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [_address setDelegate:self];
    _address.clearButtonMode =
    UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    _address.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
    [_address addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(loadAddresss)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)loadAddresss {
    NSString* urlString = _address.text;
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if(!url.scheme)
    {
        NSString* modifiedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlString];
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:modifiedURLString];
    }
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSLog(@"request= %@", request);
    NSLog(@"text= %@", urlString);
   if (request!=nil) {

       if(delegate!=nil)
       {NSLog(@"delegate not nil");
           [delegate loadSomethingFromAddressBar:request];
       }else{
           NSLog(@"delegate is nil");//There delegate always is nil
       }

    }
}


    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Make sure that your web view Outlet & Delegate is correctly conncted.`

**There no space between URL Address because I also face the same issue. Try to open that url in web-Browser.**

Answer (score 0):

If this is your view hierarchy

```
   ---- In ViewController 
       ---- Showing AddressBar View in POPOver
   ---- Remove POPover and display ViewController's web view
```

I suggest create a custom delegate method in AddressBar and when you remove the popOver trigger the  delegate method. Implement the delegate in your ViewContrller and call loadSomethingFromAddressBar in that implemented delegate method

Note : make sure you have connected you webpage IBOutlet to your nib file.

// In Adressbar.h

```
@protocol AddressbarDelegate <NSObject>
@required
   -(void)loadYourWebViewNow:(NSURLRequest*)request;
@end

@interface Addressbar : UIViewController
{
}

@property(nonatomic, weak) id <AddressbarDelegate>
```

// In Adressbar.m

```
    - (void)loadAddresss {
      NSString* urlString = _address.text; //geting text from UItextField
      NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
      if(!url.scheme)
      {
          NSString* modifiedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlString];
          url = [NSURL URLWithString:modifiedURLString];
      }
      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     if (request!=nil) {
     NSLog(@"request is good");
     if(_delegate!=nil)
     {
       [_delegate loadYourWebViewNow:request];
     }

 }
```

// In your ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AddressbarDelegate>
{
    //AdressBar *addressBar;
}
```

// In your ViewController.m implement the delegate method and set the delegate

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    Remove these two below lines  on viewDidLoad
     //addressBar = [[Adressbar alloc] init];
     //addressbar.delegate = self;
}

-(void)loadYourWebViewNow:(NSURLRequest*)request
{
    [self loadSomethingFromAddressBar:request];
}


-(void)showPopoverAdressBar:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
AdressBar *popoverControllesr = [[AdressBar alloc]init];
popoverControllesr.delegate = self; // set the delegate here to this object. 
popoverControllesr.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 600, 45);
popoverControllesr.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
popoverController = [[mypopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverControllesr];

popoverController.cornerRadius = 20;
if(_titles!=NULL){

    popoverController.titleText = _titles;}else{
        popoverController.titleText = @"Loading...";
    }
popoverControllesr.address.text = absoluteString;



popoverController.popoverBaseColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
popoverController.popoverGradient= YES;

popoverController.arrowPosition = TSPopoverArrowPositionHorizontal;
[popoverController showPopoverWithTouch:event];

}
```

Comment: I was create address bar in customize popoverView and then set in popoverView AddressBar class with textfield

Comment: Ok you mean to say you are adding addressbar class in a popover? Then your webView must be in AddressBar not in ViewController. Either your webview should be in whatever you are displaying or you must add the class which has the view as a subview for it to display on the screen ..

Comment: make sure u connect ur webpage outlet and you set the delegate as shown ..

Comment: why _delegate is nil?

Comment: set the delegate as shown

Comment: I was set all like you said but it stucks in if(_delegate!=nil)
     {
       [_delegate loadYourWebViewNow:request];
     }, because _delegate is nil.

Comment: thats not possible.. check whether you have used all the code.. if you have set the delagate in viewDidLoad method like i have shown, it sets the delegate. Can u put a break point to addressbar.delegate = self; and see if the delegate is getting set..?

Comment: Where in your code is created `_delegate` variable? It just shows: use of  undeclared identifier '_delegate'

Comment: ok the synthesize the delegate in your .m file..

Comment: _delegate still is nil!

Comment: if u want more help ul have to send me your code.. coz i cant figure out the reason

Comment: Ok, I've upgrade my question. I've share all my code.

Comment: ok.. now i understand why your delegate is nil... remove the AdressBar alloc init from viewDidLoad ... and in your showPopOverAdressBar method set the delegate to self ... popoverControllesr.delegate = self; You are setting the delegate to one object and trying to find delegate's ref from another object... Try this it will work.. Check edits in my code... i have mentioned as comments and commented some lines ...